# Proving that $\langle LT(I) \rangle$ is a monomial ideal where $I$ is an ideal.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, monomial-ideals

I am trying to prove this statement and I am very new to monomial ideals.

The definition of monomial ideal is stated like this in my book:

An ideal $I ⊆ k[x_1,..., x_n]$ is a *monomial* ideal if there is a subset $A ⊆ \mathbb Z^n_{≥0}$ (possibly infinite) such that $I$ consists of all polynomials which are finite sums of the form  $\sum_{α∈A}{h_αx^α}$, where $h_α ∈ k[x_1,..., x_n]$.

$I \ne \{0\}$, so we see that if we consider any ideal $I \subset K[x_1,...,x_n]$ then the leading terms of the polynomial will be of the form $h_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha = (a_1,...,a_n)$ and $x^{\alpha}=x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$.

Here's the answer which has been there in my book,

The leading monomials $LM(g)$ of elements $g ∈ I / \{0\}$ generate the monomial ideal $\langle LM(g) | g ∈ I / \{0\} \rangle$.

> Since $LM(g)$ and $LT(g)$ differ by a nonzero
> constant, this ideal equals $\langle LT(g) | g ∈ I \ {0} \rangle  = \langle LT(I) \rangle$ . Thus,
> $\langle LT(I) \rangle $ is a monomial ideal.

This is something I can't understand. Can someone help me please.

Comment: The ideal $LT(I)$ is by definition (more or less) generated by the leading terms of elements of $I$, which are monomials, so the ideal is generated by monomials. I am not sure I understand what you are confused about, but if you clarify it maybe I can help.

Comment: I also have a doubt over here , can the monomial ideal be like this $\langle (1,xy,x) \rangle$. I think I am confused with the idea how is the monomial ideal different from a normal ideal in $k[x_1,..x_n]$.I just need some help,maybe with the definition.

Comment: This question, despite being quite easy, is not answered in any textbook that I have seen(!). It is quite strange since for some proofs in Groebner basis, one needs to use properties of monomial ideals but in three books that I have been using there is not any such statement.